# Unfortunately my app has stopped what should I do?

Tags: android

I am getting message in AVD like - unfortunately has stopped ,please help me solve this error, I want learn more in android but sucked by this error.

xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                android:contentDescription="@null"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:contentDescription="@null"

         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="set wallpaper" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
    package com.example.second;
  public class photo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView iv;
    Button bt;
    ImageButton ib;
    Intent i ;
    Bitmap bmp;
    final static int cameraData =0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        intsallttion();
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    }
    private void intsallttion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);

        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bt:
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.ib:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }

}
```

mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.second"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".omar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.second.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



          <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.second.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



          <activity
            android:name=".TextPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity> 
           <activity
            android:name=".photo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity> 

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: post logcat values !!

Comment: Post the error log. That might help.

Comment: error log cat please !!!

Comment: In first question, you have explain well with proper code, I suggest you, In future do upload the error with question. It helps faster to solve the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add .xml file statement like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in `onCreate()` method, after this line

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Since you forgot to add the .xml your activity was not able to get the details of the component likes ImageView,Button & ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

you defined the activity omar as the first to lunch when the application is lunched, in your manifest:

```
      <activity
                android:name=".omar"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <!-- remove this intent filter if you don't want to lunch this activity first-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

and you are showing us the activity `photo`.

if you want to lunch this activity `photo`, you have to update your xml like this :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".photo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!--this intent filter detects which activity to lunch the first-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity
        android:name=".omar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- you should remove the intent filter from here -->
    </activity>
```

Furthermore, in your java code , you have to define your layout in onCreat() . so your onCreat will look like :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // I am supposing that your xml file is called  activity_photo.xml .
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
    intsallttion();
   // getRessources() : get the ressorces of your application (present in your /res folder)
   // openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher) : get "ic_launcher" from /drawable and put it in 
   // InputStream
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
   //this line creats you a Bitmap of the picture ic_launcher


    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

}
```

answer to your last comment:

In your ImageView you are putting the drawable/ic_launcher by this code `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` . This is your image view:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:contentDescription="@null"
    />
```

Then by the code , you are putting the same picture in this ImageView `drawable/ic_launcher` , which you converted to Bitmap and called bmp.
If you want to see something changing you have to remove this `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` from the image view, then click on the buttons and you will see that the picture is appearing in the ImageView. Then remove this two lines of code : `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);`

And then click in the buttons, and you will see that the picture is not appearing .
Conclusion : this two lines are taking a picture from your /res and putting it in a Bitmap. then the clickListener are putting this bitmap in the ImageView. If you delete them, the click Listeners will put an empty Bitmap in the ImageView.

Comment: can u explain to me this code InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Mr.Ahmed

Comment: why he creats it a Bitmap?

Comment: to show it in the wallpaper , see in the click Listener :
`getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);`

Comment: I updated my answer.
I am not answering in Arabic , because I don't have an Arabic keyword and because we are in an international platform; everybody should understand.
good luck